# How would I say "In what regard" or "in what respect"?

Tags: word-choice

Let's say someone says "I'm traditional", and I wanted to ask "In what respect/regard are you traditional?" How would I translate this?

Answer (score 5):

Most commonly, people say:

> 「どんな/どのような/どういう + 点{てん} + **で**」

So, you could say:

> 「どんな点で古風{こふう}なんですか。」

You will also hear:

> 「どういう意味{いみ}で古風なの/なのですか/なんですか。」

Answer (score 1):

A few more suggestions to add to the other answers:

> （あなたの）どこが（Traditional)なの？
>
> （あなたは）どんな風に(Traditional)なの？
>
> （あなたの）どんなところが(Traditional)なの？

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you could also use

> {何の・どんな}[面]{めん}で～

although I'm not completely confident in that.

Comment: 伝わりはしますが、せめて「どんな面で」の方がいいと思います。

Answer (score 0):

My immediate thought was どう言うふうに: "In what way?", or "how so?".